# How to get asdf's version to be the version

Tags: asdf-vm

Explained in terminal, I have installed a version of nodejs using asdf, but the terminal only sees the other version:

```
> asdf list
nodejs
  12.18.3

> nodejs --version
v8.10.0

> asdf global nodejs 12.18.3 

> nodejs --version          
v8.10.0
```

Have added the following to the top of .zshrc

```
. $HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh
export PATH=$HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh:$PATH
```

Have reloaded .zshrc

```
> source ~/.zshrc
```

There are no local files which are setting the local version to 8.10.0.

How do I get `nodejs --version` to give me the version that asdf acknowledges as the global version?

Comment: did you install node using the asdf cli, as in `asdf install nodejs 12.18.3`?

Comment: No, I used `asdf install` and the `.tool-versions` file has the nodejs version in it. Does that make a difference?

Comment: It may as well - I am going blindly on what you have outlined in the OQ.  And the `.tool-versions` file is in that directory with global defaults sets as `$HOME/.tool-versions`?

Comment: What does `type -a nodejs` return for you? It sounds like you've got your system node taking precedence over everything managed by asdf. The asdf directories need to come first in your `$PATH`.

Comment: it says `nodejs is /usr/bin/nodejs` three times. When I do `echo $PATH` I get `/usr/local/opt/qt@5.5/bin:/home/joe/.asdf/shims:/home/joe/.asdf/bin:` etc, so asdf is first

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had this problem on both Ubuntu 18.04 and Mac 10.15.7.
There were several issues.

Installing asdf with brew (mac) does not install it properly - `asdf.sh` is missing. [The docs](https://asdf-vm.com/#/core-manage-asdf) suggest installing with git, which works.

As stated in [the docs](https://asdf-vm.com/#/core-manage-asdf), the running of `asdf.sh` (grey box below) needs to be at the BOTTOM of .zshrc (or equivalent profile setting file, such as .bash_profile etc). It adds things to the start of the $PATH.

```
. $HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh
```

Naturally you need to run `source .zshrc` after modifying it so the terminal reloads the changes. This should result in changing your $PATH, so when you run `echo $PATH` you should have something that starts with:

```
/Users/homersimpson/.asdf/shims:/Users/homersimpson/.asdf/bin:/usr/local/opt/qt@5.5/bin: ...other things separated by ':'
```

`which node` should give something like `/Users/homersimpson/.asdf/shims/node`. It is the shims for asdf being at the start of your path which make asdf's version be the version your system uses.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to install asdf with homebrew and zsh use this:

`echo -e "\n. $(brew --prefix asdf)/libexec/asdf.sh" >> ${ZDOTDIR:-~}/.zshrc`

This adds the asdf.sh properly to the .zshrc file.

[Read about it here](https://asdf-vm.com/guide/getting-started.html#_3-install-asdf)

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue, and I noticed that it seems to happen because asdf doesn't seem to know about a version of Ruby (2.6.3) I installed via asdf today. It recommends I use one of my three previous versions of Ruby:

james@James-Precision-5520:~/Git/elixirschool$ asdf current
elixir         1.9.0-otp-22 (set by /home/james/.tool-versions)
erlang         22.0.7   (set by /home/james/.tool-versions)
ruby           2.6.3    (set by /home/james/.tool-versions)
james@James-Precision-5520:~/Git/elixirschool$ jekyll
asdf: No version set for command jekyll
you might want to add one of the following in your .tool-versions file:

ruby 2.3.7
ruby 2.4.3
ruby 2.5.1
james@James-Precision-5520:~/Git/elixirschool$ ls ~/.asdf/installs/ruby
2.3.7  2.4.3  2.5.1  2.6.3
james@James-Precision-5520:~/Git/elixirschool$ asdf list ruby
2.3.7
2.4.3
2.5.1
2.6.3
When I changed my .tool-versions to point at one of the other three (older) Ruby installs, it started working.

Answer (score 0):

If you're already sourcing asdf in your zshrc, then this can be fixed by running:

```
asdf install TOOLCHAIN VERSION
```

and then running the global command again:

```
asdf global TOOLCHAIN VERSION
```

it seems I either neither ran the install before or somehow it got removed either by updating asdf or something else

Answer (score 0):

If you installed node with Homebrew then you'll probably see something like this when you run `which node` which tells you the brew version is being used:

```
/opt/homebrew/bin/node
```

If you remove node from brew by running `brew uninstall node` then `which node` will likely flip over to the asdf version and you'll see something like:

```
/Users/you/.asdf/shims/node
```

Also, since you're using ZSH it's easiest to just use the asdf plugin like `plugins=(asdf)` in your `.zshrc`: https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/asdf